# ObjectDataSource and Collection of Objects

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, objectdatasource

I have a GridView that I would like to bind to an ObjectDataSource.  I have a ReadOnlyCollection of business objects that have many properties.  I only to need to display four of these properties in the GridView.  I haven't used the ObjectDataSource control before, so how can I use it to display 4 properties of all of the business objects in my ReadOnlyCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you had a list of objects with two properties: Name & Age:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwExample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  DataSourceId="myObjectDataSource">
  <columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
  </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Same thing you would do if you were data binding against any source and didn't want every value of each row of data.